# How to develop app that starts automatically and always runs in background

Tags: development

I'm developing my first application for Ubuntu, and part of the apps functionality will involve displaying notifications based on dates that are in a SQLite database. How can I get the app to automatically perform a task every day at certain times, without the user having to run the app. So basically I would need the app to always run in the background, I think?

(I'm using python and GTK+3)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is more apt for [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), but valid none-the-less. You're looking for what is known as a daemon in the *nix world. A daemon is a background service that is usually started automatically on boot, but can be invoked at any time.

I haven't had much experience with python-based daemons (only C), but the concepts are similar. See [this](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/) daemon-skeleton code from the Python Cookbook. All you have to do is override the `run()` method in the derived MyDaemon class.

If having an extra class for the sole purpose of daemon-izing is overkill (I can't see how, but anyway), try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718821/run-python-script-as-daemon-at-boot-time-ubuntu) (found at stackoverflow) :)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. So would the script automatically run on boot? Does it need to be stored somewhere in particular?

Comment: yes, the script should run automatically. Generally, boot-up scripts need to be stored in the `/etc/init.d` directory